# C# reusing my interfaces for database access

Tags: c#, blazor

I am relatively new to c# and have only been a developer for a couple years. I followed this really great tutorial on how to make a library with data models and interfaces to handle retrieving and inserting data into my database. I am working on a Blazor server side application. I utilize my data access library by injecting its interface onto the razor page via a service created in the startup.cs. All of this works fantastically.

However, Now I am making class that reads delimited files and inserts the data into the database table. I would like to use the same interfaces in my data access library that I use to connect my razor pages to the back end.

Here is my class where I want to use the InsertPermit method from IpermitData to insert a record to my database table but _db is null and will give me a null reference exception when I run it. How can I get a handle on this interface so I can use it to insert data?

```
{
public class TextFileParser
{
    public TextFileParser()
    {

    }

    public void InsertTextFileData(string filePath)
    {
        string errMessage = string.Empty;
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (!File.Exists(file.FullName))
        {
            errMessage = "File not found!";
        }
        else if (file.Length >= 0)
        {
            errMessage = "File has no data!";
        }

        IPermitData _db;

        PermitModel permitRecord = new PermitModel();
        string vText = string.Empty;
        string[] vString;
        string delimiter = "\t";
        StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(filePath);

        List<PermitModel> dt = new List<PermitModel>();
        //dt.Add("Parcel Number");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Permit ID");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Construction Loc");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Submission Date");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Issue Date");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Permit Type");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Const. Addr.");
        //dt.Columns.Add("EST Cost");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Referrer");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Comments");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Status");

        int header = 1;

        while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            if (header == 1)
            {
                header += 1;
                vText = fileReader.ReadLine();
                vString = vText.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None);
                continue;
            }

            vText = fileReader.ReadLine();
            vString = vText.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None);
            permitRecord.PD_ParcelID = vString[0];
            permitRecord.PD_Situs1 = vString[1];
            permitRecord.PD_Owner = vString[2];
            permitRecord.PD_Addr1 = vString[3];
            permitRecord.PD_Addr2 = vString[4];
            permitRecord.ADDR_3 = vString[5];
            permitRecord.PD_City = vString[6];
            permitRecord.PD_State = vString[7];
            permitRecord.PD_Zip = vString[8];
            permitRecord.Type_Construction = vString[9];
            permitRecord.Estimated_Cost = vString[10];
            permitRecord.Permit_Issue_Date = vString[11];
            permitRecord.Permit_Type = vString[12];
            permitRecord.Property_Type = vString[13];
            permitRecord.Permit_NO = vString[14];
            permitRecord.Completion_Date = vString[15];
            permitRecord.Percent_Complete = vString[16];
            permitRecord.Modified_Date = vString[17];
            permitRecord.Note = vString[18];
            permitRecord.Note_Date = vString[19];
            permitRecord.Submission_Date = vString[20];
            permitRecord.Submitter = vString[21];
            permitRecord.Submitter_Phone = vString[22];
            permitRecord.Submitter_Email = vString[23];
            permitRecord.Land_AV = vString[24];
            permitRecord.Impr_AV = vString[25];
            permitRecord.Sec_Location = vString[26];



            try
            {
                _db.InsertPermit(permitRecord);

            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                // dt.Add(vString[0], vString[14], vString[1], vString[20], vString[11], vString[12], vString[26], vString[10], vString[21], vString[18], "Failed " + ex.Message);
                //dt.Add(permitRecord);

                continue;
            }

            //dt.Rows.Add(vString[0], vString[14], vString[1], vString[20], vString[11], vString[12], vString[26], vString[10], vString[21], vString[18], "Passed");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Here are the code files from my dataaccesslibrary.

```
public interface IPermitData
{
    Task<List<PermitModel>> GetPermitData();
    Task InsertPermit(PermitModel permit);
    Task DeletePermit(PermitModel permit);
}

public class PermitData : IPermitData
{
    private readonly ISqlDataAccess _db;

    public PermitData(ISqlDataAccess db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Task<List<PermitModel>> GetPermitData()
    {
        string sql = "select * from dbo.I_Permit";

        return _db.LoadData<PermitModel, dynamic>(sql, new { });
    }

    public Task InsertPermit(PermitModel permit)
    {
        string sql = @"insert into dbo.I_Permit ( Parcel, Location, Owner_Name, ADDR_1, ADDR_2, ADDR_3, City, State_Sh, Zipcode, Type_Construction, Estimated_Cost, Permit_Issue_Date, Permit_Type, Property_Type, Permit_NO, Completion_Date, Percent_Complete, Modified_Date, Note, Note_Date, Submission_Date, Submitter, Submitter_Phone, Submitter_Email, Land_AV, Impr_AV, Sec_Location, PD_Owner, PD_Name2, PD_Addr1, PD_Addr2, PD_City, PD_State, PD_Zip, PD_ControlNo, PD_ParcelID, PD_Situs1, PD_Situs2, PD_S_City, PD_S_State, PS_S_Zip )
                     values ( @Parcel, @Location, @Owner_Name, @ADDR_1, @ADDR_2, @ADDR_3, @City, @State_Sh, @Zipcode, @Type_Construction, @Estimated_Cost, @Permit_Issue_Date, @Permit_Type, @Property_Type, @Permit_NO, @Completion_Date, @Percent_Complete, @Modified_Date, @Note, @Note_Date, @Submission_Date, @Submitter, @Submitter_Phone, @Submitter_Email, @Land_AV, @Impr_AV, @Sec_Location, @PD_Owner, @PD_Name2, @PD_Addr1, @PD_Addr2, @PD_City, @PD_State, @PD_Zip, @PD_ControlNo, @PD_ParcelID, @PD_Situs1, @PD_Situs2, @PD_S_City, @PD_S_State, @PS_S_Zip )";

        return _db.SaveData(sql, permit);
    }
    public Task DeletePermit(PermitModel permit)
    {
        string sql = @"DELETE FROM dbo.I_Permit WHERE Record_ID =' " + permit.Record_ID + " ';";

        return _db.DeleteData(sql, permit);

    }
}
public interface ISqlDataAccess
{
    string ConnectionStringName { get; set; }

    Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters);
    Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters);
    Task DeleteData<T>(string sql, T parameters);
}

public class SqlDataAccess : ISqlDataAccess
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public string ConnectionStringName { get; set; } = "Default";


    public SqlDataAccess(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> LoadData<T, U>(string sql, U parameters)
    {
        string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var data = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(sql, parameters);

            return data.ToList();
        }
    }

    public async Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters)
    {
        string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
        }
    }

    public async Task DeleteData<T>(string sql, T parameters)
    {
        string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringName);

        using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be using `SqlParameter` to pass values, and writing things like `DELETE FROM dbo.I_Permit WHERE Record_ID =  @recordId` for the actual query. Otherwise, if `Record_ID` is `' OR 1 = 1` then it will form the query `DELETE FROM dbo.I_Permit WHERE Record_ID ='' OR 1 = 1` and all of the records in the table will be deleted (this kind of attack is called SQL Injection).

Comment: Done! Thank you for the tip! my sql command looks like this now and it works perfectly!

"string sql = @"DELETE FROM dbo.I_Permit WHERE Record_ID = @Record_ID";"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to the community! The nice thing about .Net core is it makes the dependency injection system work very smoothly. So in your constructor for your parser, you just need to inject what you need from your data access layer. An example with your PermitData class would look like this:

```cs
public class TextFileParser
{
    private IPermitData _permitData;

    public TextFileParser(IPermitData permitData)
    {
        this._permitData= permitData;
    }

    // code that uses your injected service
    _permitData.MethodToDoWorkEtc();
}
```

Notice that in the constructor you call for the interface you need as I have it written, but you can also call for a concrete class if that is how your dependency injection is set up. It then populates a backing field in your class with the injected service, and you use the backing field as the start point to do the work that needs done.

The DI framework will pick this all up when you build your app and assemble it for you, so as long as the service is registered in the Startup.cs file, you shouldn't need anything else. This method will also allow you to compose simple services together into larger more advanced services while keeping the simple parts separated for better testing and portability.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh man! That was so easy!!!! I was ripping my hair out trying to new an instance of the implementation of the interface but then I needed a configuration object but I couldnt figure out how to just just the json file as the configuration and pass that. I was ripping my hair out THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help. For me, it took forever to get the concept that DI will hand the constructor whatever it's asking for, but the flexibility it provides is amazing. Say you have an IDatabase implementation that accesses an SQL server, but you want to change to Mongo. Just build up the Mongo service and implement IDatabase on it, change the Startup.cs to use the Mongo version instead, rebuild and you're done. You just switched databases by writing out the new service and changing 1 line of core code. Same concept for email providers, loggers, etc.